# No sound playback in Videos (elementary OS Freya 0.3.2)

Tags: release-freya, sound, videos

After some time off from elementary OS, I went back in, logged and now I'm not getting any audio playback from the Videos (0.1.0.2) app.

I have sound in my browser, Music (0.3.1) app, and general system, I even installed VLC and I have sound with it to, but nothing on Videos, I've have tried with various files (.mp4, .avi, .mkv) and nothing.

I updated my system and it did nothing.

Comment: Facing same issue on Elementary Loki as well.